# Need A Solution To Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Let me explain to you the problem I am facing. I am building an eCommerce application. When the user sign-up only his location i.e latitude and longitude are saved in the firebase database. I have also made a profile update section where users can set their username, email, and phone number. But the username and email are not stored and are unavailable for the time being, I just want to show USERNAME and EMAIL written there. But I am facing Bad state: the field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform , I know that the field does not exist as I have not stored their name and email. So now I want to do is that if username and email are present show the username and email else just show USERNAME and EMAIL in their place. Want to do this without getting Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform error.
Providing my code so that fellow developer friends can update the existing code.

PROFILE_SCREEEN.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/providers/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/providers/location_provider.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/screens/map_screen.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/screens/profile_update_screen.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = 'profile-screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var userDetails = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    userDetails.getUserDetails();
    var location = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context);
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          centerTitle: true,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          title: const Text(
            "Grocery Store",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 40,
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    child: Text(
                                      userDetails.documentSnapshot != null
                                          ? "${userDetails.documentSnapshot?['firstName'].toString().substring(0, 1)}"
                                          : "1",
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 10,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 70,
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          userDetails.documentSnapshot != null
                                              ? "${userDetails.documentSnapshot?['firstName']} ${userDetails.documentSnapshot?['lastName']}"
                                              : "Update Your Name",
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                        if (userDetails
                                                .documentSnapshot?['email'] !=
                                            null)
                                          Text(
                                            "${userDetails.documentSnapshot?['email']}",
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        Text(
                                          user!.phoneNumber.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              if (userDetails.documentSnapshot != null)
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    leading: const Icon(
                                      Icons.location_on,
                                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                    ),
                                    title: Text(userDetails
                                        .documentSnapshot?['location']),
                                    subtitle: Text(
                                      userDetails.documentSnapshot?['address'],
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                    ),
                                    trailing: OutlinedButton(
                                      child: Text("Change"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        EasyLoading.show(
                                            status: "Please Wait...");
                                        location
                                            .getMyCurrentPosition()
                                            .then((value) {
                                          if (value != null) {
                                            EasyLoading.dismiss();
                                            pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(
                                              context,
                                              settings: const RouteSettings(
                                                  name: MapScreen.id),
                                              screen: const MapScreen(),
                                              pageTransitionAnimation:
                                                  PageTransitionAnimation
                                                      .cupertino,
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            EasyLoading.dismiss();
                                            print("Permission Not Allowed");
                                          }
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                          right: 10.0,
                          top: 10.0,
                          child: IconButton(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onPressed: () {
                              pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(
                                context,
                                settings:
                                    const RouteSettings(name: UpdateProfile.id),
                                withNavBar: false,
                                screen: const UpdateProfile(),
                                pageTransitionAnimation:
                                    PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                              );
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit_outlined),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leading: Icon(Icons.history),
                      title: Text("My Orders"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leading: Icon(Icons.comment_outlined),
                      title: Text("My Ratings And Reviews"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leading: Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
                      title: Text("Notifications"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leading: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new),
                      title: Text("Logout"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#public-boolean-contains-fieldpath-fieldpath) method of `DocumentSnapshot` to check whether a field exists or not, and then do your logic based on that.

Comment: Great, will try your solution out. Thanks

Comment: Friend, I can't find any method with the name contains, the available methods are exists, id, metadata, hashcode, etc. If possible please modify some lines of the mentioned code for my reference

Comment: Did you click through the link I provided? You might be trying to access this method on an object that is not a `DocumentSnapshot`.